# Can we use Spring Webflux with spring data jdbc template? What will be the impact? what to do in such situation where we can not use R2DBC?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, spring-reactive, spring-reactor

I am new to spring web flux and not sure how to integrate it with the existing spring jdbc template which uses blocking persistence driver for the oracle. i.e.. in my situation R2DBC (oracle) is not supported/not available. I must have to use oracle-jdbc driver with spring data jdbc.

Comment: if you read the faq you will find how to deal with blocking calls https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle R2DBC driver was recently released open-source on GitHub:
https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc